# sharepoint calculated column to round a number

Tags: 2010, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I want to calculate a field value such that if it is less then 0.5 it would be round up to 0.5 (ex. .3 would be .5, 1.3 would be 1.5, 2.1 would be 2.5) and if the value is greater then 1.5 ti would be round up to the next integer(ex. .6 would be 1, 1.7 would be 2, 2.6 would be 3)

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is a ceiling function. SharePoint does not have such a function, but you can roll your own with the Roundup function. Create a calculated column and use this (replace "TheNumber" with your number column). Ensure your calculated column is of type "Number".

```
=ROUNDUP([TheNumber]*2,0)/2
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! Very useful!